# Auto-create index fields on sub documents in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, indexing

My collection is something like this:

```
{
_id: ObjectId(...),
productName: "some product",
colours: [{colourName:"orange",stock:5},{colourName:"red",stock:1}]
}
```

Is it possible to get mongo to autocreate an _id field for each colour subdocument as well as each inserted main document? I want to do this so that when a user performs "add 1 colour red to basket" I can identify the product and colour easily by putting the colour id as a hidden field in the form.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily create these extra _id fields in your application. In the Java driver, for example, you can do `new ObjectId()`. I believe that's what the MongoDB client does for the main _id field, too.